# writing from a Spark DataFrame to BigQuery table gives BigQueryException: Provided Schema does not match

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

My PySpark computes a DataFrame that I want to insert into a BigQuery table (from a dataproc cluster).
On the BigQuery side, the partition field is REQUIRED.
On the DataFrame side, the partition field inferred is not REQUIRED, that is why I make a schema defining this field as REQUIRED :

> StructField("date_part",DateType(),False)

So, I create a new DF with the new schema and when I show this DF, I see as expected :

> date_part: date (nullable = false)

But my PySpark ended like that :

> Caused by: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Provided Schema does not match Table xyz$20211115. Field date_part has changed mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE

Is there something I missed ?

Update :

- I am using Spark 3.0 image
- And spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar connector

Comment: Hi, the error is pretty clear. BigQuery and Dataframe have different schemas. If this doesn't help, probably providing more information will help to understand your case better.